# Springboot HornetQJMS, Message client acknowledge not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I've spring boot HornetQ jms(an external server) configured and it works on positive scenario.However I'm trying to remove the message from queue only if there is no error(acknowledge the message if there is no error) by configuring ack mode as client. However when I see the queue, the messages are removed. Here is spring boot configurations.

```
    @Component
    public class JmsMessageListener {

         private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsMessageListener.class);

         @JmsListener(destination = "KpRqQueue")
         public void onMessage(TextMessage message) {

        TextMessage txtMsg = message;
        String txt;
        try {
            txt = txtMsg.getText();
            LOG.info("Hey I recevied a message {}", txt);
            if ("Hello".equals(txt)) {
                throw new JMSException("An error");
            }
            message.acknowledge();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is configuration file.

```
spring.hornetq.mode=native
spring.hornetq.host=localhost
spring.hornetq.port=5445
spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=CLIENT
```

How to enable client acknowledgement mode. And also let me know how to manually create `defaulemessagelistenercontainer.`

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? that last property was added recently and is only available as of `1.3.0.M4`

Comment: I'm using Spring boot version 1.3.0.M4

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem then, sorry. Can you rephrase maybe?

Comment: In short, I'm trying to remove the message from hornetq if onmessage method is successfully executed and if there is any error thrown in onmessage method message must not be removed from queue. Hence I'm trying to configure Client ack mode.

Comment: well, no need for client mode for that. Just throw an exception with the default settings when there is an error and your message will be delivered again.

Comment: Yeah thanks for heads up...... I was looking at wrong Queue. After 10(default) redelivery attempts it was moving the message to DLQ queue.